# In Groovy, how do I get the type of an object created with `[$class: ClassName, attr1: value]`?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In a Jenkins pipeline script I'm dealing with an `scm` object and need to read attributes like `CloneOption` or `PathRestriction`. The `scm` object has been created like this:

```
scm = [
    $class: "GitSCM",
    extensions: [
        [$class: 'CloneOption',timeout: 20],
        [$class: 'PathRestriction',
            includedRegions: "some-pattern"],
    ]]
```

To access the path restrictions I tried a loop like this:

```
scm.extensions.each {
    if (it instanceof PathRestriction) {
        print(it)
    }
}
```

But `instanceof` doesn't seem to match on any `it`. I tried check `it.getClass()` or `it.class`, but for those I only get `LinkedHashMap` and `null`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I access those attributes?

**Update**

I'm now doing it like this:

```
scm.extensions.each {
    if (it.get("\$class") == "PathRestriction") {
        print(it);
    }
}
```

.. but that can't be the way to go, can it?

Comment: why not if it's just a string in declaration?

Comment: I agree with @daggett. Looks ok to me. You can, of course, do something like `Class.forName(it.get("\$class")) instanceof PathRestriction`, but then you will need to change the configuration string from `PathRestriction` to the name with package `my.packege.PathRestriction`. I see no point in it.